# Errors installing Yo and while using angular generator

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to install Yeoman using NPM, but am greeted by the following error:

```
Jaspers-MacBook-Pro:Sites Jasper$ sudo npm install --global yo

> fullname-native@0.1.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fullname/node_modules/fullname-native
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EPERM, utime '/Users/Jasper/.node-gyp/0.10.29'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fullname/node_modules/fullname-native
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues>
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fullname-native@0.1.1
/usr/local/bin/yo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js

> yo@1.2.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
> node ./scripts/doctor

[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!

npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data requires async@'~0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.2.10
```

Since Yeoman doctor says "looks allright", I tried to install te angular generator

`npm install -g generator-angular
yo angular`

This just returned some more errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'grunt-karma' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma-phantomjs-launcher" "karma-jasmine" "grunt-karma" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Jasper/Sites/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Jasper/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'load-grunt-tasks' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Jasper/Sites/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/Jasper/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Jasper/Sites/test/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've tried to update node-gyp, uninstalled node and reinstalled via homebrew but with no success...

if I install the generator with sudo, running `yo angular` returns the following

`npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma-phantomjs-launcher" "karma-jasmine" "grunt-karma" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/Jasper/.npm/mkdirp/0.3.5/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jasper/.npm/mkdirp/0.3.5/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Jasper/.npm/lodash/2.4.1/package/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0`

Don't see why this isn't working, as I had it working before

I'm on a clean install of OSX Mavericks

Jasper

Comment: Your second command needs `sudo` prepended as well. Though this might nto solve all your issues, I don't like the look of output from running 1st command.

Comment: @alandarev tried sudo with pretty much everything... no joy :(

Comment: I did nto say it will sort your problems. but the output of second command is "Sorry Jasper, I have no rights". Thus we cannot see any meaningful log from 2nd command.  You indeed have something going on from 1st command, as a result second shall fail too.

Comment: Good one.... 
was in a bit of a hurry, I'll post the sudo output ;)

Comment: I installed npm on a clean Mountain Lion and now have the exact same problem with yo and angular generator. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue. Get started with fixing the permissions issue:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

It's a popular issue: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm new to Linux/Mac and this helped me out greatly. Cheers!